# XML per XLST to HTML from multiple files

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to transform language specific XML-data into html. I can still change much of the setup and try to figure out how to do it best.

- Products will have multiple xml-files (one per language, one per product), like Product1_EN.xml, Product1_DE.xml with a `<PackageInsert lang="xy">`-tag. (I split at this level so I can later select per URL).
- There will be a `Languages.xml`-file with multiple `<Language lang="xy">`-tags.

This is my `PackageInsert.xsl`-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html><head>
  </head><body>
    <xsl:for-each select="PackageInsert/Product">
      <h1>Product: <xsl:value-of select="Name"/></h1>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body></html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have the following in my `Product.xml`-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="PackageInsert.xsl"?>
<PackageInsert lang="EN">
  <Product>
    <Name>AwesomeProduct<sup>®</sup></Name>
  </Product>
</PackageInsert>
```

This will translate to the following resulting html:

```
<html><head>
</head><body>
  <h1>Product: AwesomeProduct<sup>®</sup></h1>
</body></html>
```

I also have the following `Languages.xml`-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Language lang="EN">
  <Product>Product</Product>
</Language>
<Language lang="DE">
  <Product>Produkt</Product>
</Language>
```

How can I bring them together, so that the currently hardcoded "Product"-part of the `PackageInsert.xsl` will come from the `Languages.xml`'s \Language[lang="EN"]\Product-Entry, selected by the `Product.xml`'s lang="EN"-attribute?

The expected result would be:

(pseudocode):
if \PackageInsert[lang=="EN"]: {

```
<html><head>
</head><body>
  <h1>Product: AwesomeProduct<sup>®</sup></h1>
</body></html>
```

} elseif \PackageInsert[lang=="DE"]: {

```
<html><head>
</head><body>
  <h1>Produkt: AwesomeProduct<sup>®</sup></h1>
</body></html>
```

}

Comment: Please clarify: (1) Will there be multiple products in the Product.xml and Languages.xml files and if so, what links a product to its name/s?  (2) What is the expected result in your example?  (3) Are you limited to XSLT 1.0?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm not limited to XSLT 1.0. I added more clarification.

Comment: Your `Languages.xml` file is not a valid xml-file. It should only contain one root element.

Comment: FYI, if you are running the transformation in a browser, then you ARE limited to XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Languages.xml` file contains a **well-formed XML document**, e.g.

```
<Languages>
    <Language lang="EN">
        <Product>Product</Product>
    </Language>
    <Language lang="DE">
        <Product>Produkt</Product>
    </Language>
</Languages>
```

then you can get your expected result using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/PackageInsert">
    <html>
        <head/>
        <body>
            <h1>
                <xsl:value-of select="document('Languages.xml')/Languages/Language[@lang=current()/@lang]/Product"/>
                <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Product/Name/node()"/>
            </h1>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```